# How to open files via block device

Tags: c, linux, file-io, io

From [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460057/HDD-FS-O_SYNC-Throughput-vs-Integrity), it compares the write on a regular file system:

```
fd = open("/media/mount1/file", O_SYNC);
```

to the write on a block device:

```
fd = open("/dev/sda", O_SYNC)
```

How can it open the same `file` inside the HDD via block device?

Comment: How do you mean "the same file"?

Comment: I assume like that because the article is talking about data integrity and throughput, seems like a comparison of reading/writing normal data (hence file). While actually we cannot do anything useful when opening HDD as a block device.

Answer (score 2):

The article does not compare writting to a file via the file system vs writting to the same file via raw access to the block device, but compares some factors, such as data integrity and speed when the `write` operation is performed in a regular file using the file system, versus a `write` performed to a block device. It doesn't open the same file using both methods. In fact, writting a regular file is way different than writting to a block device. It's just the way Linux exposes devices which allows the same system call to be used with the same semantics but to different devices. Much the same way `fprintf()` does to print to the console, or to the printer, or to a serial port, or to a file: same function, same semantics, only one argument specifies the destination.

As the article shows, a `write` operation via file system is generally faster (to the user), because the system call returns before the actual write to the disk is performed. That means that there is a (generally small) amount of time in which something that is scheduled to be written is not yet written, so a shortgage of electrical power may render to data loss. In the other hand, a write to the block device ensures data integrity and therefore, the system call returns after data is actually written to the disk (or to the cache of that disk)

Comment: so actually there is no use talking about opening HDD as block device, it doesn't make sense opening HDD as raw I/O. If you write to the HDD as block device, I think the HDD file system will be broken. The statement about data integrity and throughput in the article looks like as if we can write data to HDD normally:
"4. O_SYNC on HDD via block-device directly guarantees data-integrity but offers the low throughput."
"6. Disabling HDD data-barrier and raw DIRECT-I/O via the block device provides maximum throughput to a HDD."

Comment: After thinking about it, so if I open the HDD via block device with O_SYNC and O_DIRECT and then call fsync, does it mean all of the data in disc's own cache/buffer will be written to the disc plate when calling fsync? For example: I open hdd file via file system, write data to it and fsync the file (this does not mean the disc's cache is written to disc plate), then I open again the hdd via block device and call fsync, will it flush the disc cache from previous write command to disc plate?

Answer (score 0):

The block device in Linux gives you access to the raw bytes on the device, without the file-system translation.

To access a file inside the byte-stream of the block device, you have to implement, even if partially, the logic of the filesystem itself in your program.

So, the sort answer is, if you have to ask this, it is not possible :-)

Even though some filesystem have a simplistic logic (think FAT 32), you won't gain anything emulating the FS logic on user-space.

The exceptional case is if your application will organize the data in the block device itself, with a custom data structure rather than relying on any filesystem there (high performance configuration scenarios for some RDBMS do this kind of stuff). But this does not seen to be your case.

Answer (score 0):

With a userspace filesystem. This is the basis of the microkernel approach to operating systems, used by GNU Hurd (forever unfinished) and QNX. It is also available as fuse for Linux, e.g. fuse-ntfs.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question is that "you cannot open the same file directly via the block device interface."

The claim that "O_SYNC for a file does not guarantee commitment of data to the non-volatile storage medium of your storage device" with no qualification is dubious. The storage device may be employing or may be possible to be configured to employ write-through cache and indicate completion of the write only when actually committed to the physical medium.  Also, the OS (depending on the file-system) may implement the O_SYNC option by explicitly invoking the cache-flush command of the storage drive.

There do exist storage devices, especially those backed by NAND-flash, such as what people usually call "USB-keys" or SD-cards, that resist any attempt for implementing transactions (i.e., they claim to support to cache flush command but return before the data is actually committed) but magnetic-disk-backed systems should be possible to configure so that O_SYNC on the file (vs. the block device) guarantees commitment to the physical medium.